# Code-behind for DataTemplate defined in a ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate, code-behind

I've defined a DataTemplate in a ResourceDictionary. The template need some data (for populating a ListBox). Previously the template was a UserControl and the data was provided by setting the DataContext property.

Is there some way of using code-behind for a DataTemplate or is using an ObjectDataProvider to provide the data the only option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't provide data to the `DataTemplate`, it's the other way around : you provide a `DataTemplate` to display some data. For instance, use a `ContentControl`, and set its `Content` to the data you want to display :

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding SomeData}" />
```

The `ContentControl` will pick the adequate `DataTemplate` based on the type of the data. You can also specify the `DataTemplate` explicitly by using the `ContentTemplate` property of the `ContentControl`